# Communicating between the desktop Apps and Windows store app

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, communication, shared-memory

I want to share an image file between Desktop application and the windows store application. What is the best way to do the communication between the desktop app and the windows store app.I have tried creating the shared memory between the apps, but i think this is not possible( [Reference](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2012/08/21/can-windows-8-apps-share-memory/) ).

Comment: Place the image in the `Pictures` (or some other) library which both desktop and store apps can access.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to communicate and share date directly, except launching via protocol handler. As Aniruddha already said sharing via Filesystem (e.g. pictures library) is a convenient way to do it.

If you are on Windows 8.1 and don't have the requirement to put your application in the public Windows Store there's another option: 
Windows Runtime Brokered Components. This is quite awesome stuff. It allows you to freely communicate between a Windows Store App and any other application. It is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn630195.aspx

The setup isn't exactly easy but it is very powerful. Keep in mind that you won't get this app published into the public Windows store, if you're using brokered components.

I haven't tried Brokered Components on Windows 10 yet, I'm not sure if this is still supported.